# Running an AWS cli command from a local python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to run this aws s3 ls command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://path/to/my/bucket/12434 --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

with this python:

```
command = 'aws s3 ls s3://path/to/my/bucket/12434 --recursive --human-readable --summarize'
s3_folder_data  = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print s3_folder_data
```

But it's failing with this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'aws s3 ls s3://path/to/my/bucket/12434 --recursive --human-readable --summarize' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The command itself works when I run it. The python script is being called by the same user on the same machine. What gives?

Comment: there is a python api for aws called boto2, use it instead

Comment: here is the link for s3 -  http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware. But this was supposed to be a quick and dirty script. I don't want to go through the trouble of configuring boto if I can just use the CLI.

Comment: there is no trouble, that's the thing, it's pretty simple to use, btw check out the other question i linked

Comment: Also, that question tells me nothing about why that aws command would return with a nonzero status when it works after running it in the same environment as the same user.

Comment: it tells everything and shows how to check it deeper but it's up to you to use it

Comment: Boto does not have an equivalent command to `s3 ls`. Getting byte size of buckets is non-trivial.

Comment: are you kidding me? get_bucket() and list it

Comment: @midori : the list on boto s3 module has a limit for 1000 (also delete )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested by others, use [Boto3 S3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html) library to get what you want. But if you insist on `subprocess`, try:

```
subprocess.check_output(['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://path/to/my/bucket/12434', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://path/to/my/bucket/12434', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```

and build on it.

Answer (score 5):

New in Python 3.5, you can also use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

```
subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://path/to/my/bucket/12434', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```